# Validate Enum directly in controller function

Tags: typescript, rest, nestjs

I have a query parameter in my REST API, which values should be restricted by an enum type. I'm looking for a way to throw a "Bad Request" error, when a client gives something different.

My enum looks like this:

```
export enum Precision {
    S = 's',
    MS = 'ms',
    U = 'u',
    NS = 'ns',
}
```

My controller function looks like this:

```
  @Get(':deviceId/:datapoint/last')
  @ApiOkResponse()
  @ApiQuery({name: 'precision', enum: Precision})
  getLastMeasurement(
    @Param('deviceId') deviceId: string,
    @Param('datapoint') datapoint: string,
    @Query('precision') precision: Precision = Precision.S,
    @Res() response: Response,
  ) {
    console.log(precision);
    ....
    response.status(HttpStatus.OK).send(body);
  }
```

My problem here is that the function accepts other values, too (for example I can send an f as the query parameter's value). The Function won't return an error to the client, but I want to without writing an if else block at the beginning of each controller function.
I guess there is a rather simple solution to this, but when I try to look it up on the internet I always get results for class validation in DTOs, but not for a simple enum validation directly in the query param/REST controller.

Thanks for your time,
J

Answer (score 14):

There is 2 issues here.

The first one is that you are passing the default value of `precision` params in the wrong way. You must use the `DefaultValuePipe` like this:

```
getLastMeasurement(
  ... // some other params
    @Query('precision', new DefaultValuePipe(Precision.S)) precision: Precision
  ) { 
  ... // do something
}
```

The second one is the enum validation. NestJS comes with only 6 types of validationPipes and none of them validates an enum, so you must create your own custom validation pipe to validate enums.

There is 2 possible ways that you can do that:

1. Create a custom pipe to validate only your specific enum;
2. Create a custom pipe generic to validate any enum;

Based on this https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#custom-pipes, it would be something like:

1. Validate only the specific enum

```
import { BadRequestException, PipeTransform } from '@nestjs/common';
import { isDefined, isEnum } from 'class-validator';

export class PrecisionValidationPipe implements PipeTransform<string, Promise<Precision>> {

  transform(value: string): Promise<Precision> {
    if (isDefined(value) && isEnum(value, Precision)) {
      return Precision[value];
    } else {
      const errorMessage = `the value ${value} is not valid. See the acceptable values: ${Object.keys(
        Precision
      ).map(key => Precision[key])}`;
      throw new BadRequestException(errorMessage);
    }
  }
}
```

and then in your request, it would be like

```
  getLastMeasurement(
    @Query('precision', PrecisionValidationPipe, new DefaultValuePipe(Precision.S)) precision: Precision,
  ) {
    console.log(precision);
    ....
    response.status(HttpStatus.OK).send(body);
  }
```

2. Validate any enum (my favorite)

```
import { BadRequestException, Injectable, PipeTransform } from '@nestjs/common';
import { isDefined, isEnum } from 'class-validator';

@Injectable()
export class EnumValidationPipe implements PipeTransform<string, Promise<any>> {
  constructor(private enumEntity: any) {}
  transform(value: string): Promise<any> {
      if (isDefined(value) && isEnum(value, this.enumEntity)) {
        return this.enumEntity[value];
      } else {
        const errorMessage = `the value ${value} is not valid. See the acceptable values: ${Object.keys(this.enumEntity).map(key => this.enumEntity[key])}`;
        throw new BadRequestException(errorMessage);
      }
  }
}
```

and then in your request, it would be like

```
  getLastMeasurement(
    @Query('precision', new EnumValidationPipe(Precision), new DefaultValuePipe(Precision.S)) precision: Precision,
  ) {
    console.log(precision);
    ....
    response.status(HttpStatus.OK).send(body);
  }
```

Comment: For the error message, `Object.values(this.enumEntity)` is enough (instead of the `Object.keys` followed by the `map`).

Comment: I second @JaviMarzán, though I would like to also add `.join(', ')` will make the readout a bit neater too.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to create a class like `LastMeasurementQueryParams` that makes use of [class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validation-decorators) decorators, and use the [built-in ValidationPipe](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation) to check and make sure that one of the expected values are sent in.

The class could look something like this:

```js
export class LastMeasurementQueryParams {

  @IsEnum(Precision)
  precision: Precision;
}
```

And then your controller can look like this:

```js
  @Get(':deviceId/:datapoint/last')
  @ApiOkResponse()
  @ApiQuery({name: 'precision', enum: Precision})
  getLastMeasurement(
    @Param('deviceId') deviceId: string,
    @Param('datapoint') datapoint: string,
    @Query('precision') precision: LastMeasurementQueryParams = { precision: Precision.S },
    @Res() response: Response,
  ) {
    console.log(precision);
    ....
    response.status(HttpStatus.OK).send(body);
  }
```

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for your answer. When I read your approach I wonder how the framework should know how to transform a query parameter into a member of an object, which has to be created, too? Anyways I tested your approach, but got an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined

Comment: Hi @JWo I am currently facing the same issue as you, seems like you need to remove the TS typing from the query variable to make it work but it affects the rest of the code. 
Have you found a good solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Just improved a bug in Raphael's answer, it was returning the key of the enum instead of the value.

Also, used the metadata param to outpput on the error message the name of the field being validated and also changed

```
${Object.keys(this.enumEntity).map(key => this.enumEntity[key])}
```

to

```
${Object.values(this.enumEntity)}
```

There is the final code of the validator:

```
@Injectable()
export class EnumValidationPipe implements PipeTransform<string, Promise<any>> {
  constructor(private enumEntity: any) {}
  transform(value: string, metadata: ArgumentMetadata): Promise<any> {
    if (isDefined(value) && isEnum(value, this.enumEntity)) {
      return Promise.resolve(value);
    } else {
      const errorMessage = `the value ${value} from field ${
        metadata.data
      } is not valid. Acceptable values: ${Object.values(this.enumEntity)}`;
      throw new BadRequestException(errorMessage);
    }
  }
}
```